# How to render motion trails (paths)?

Tags: animation

I have a simple character animation from mixamo which is moving in circle (as in screenshot). Is there any method to track the path of specific vertices (eg: the motion of hand) and render the path? I tried Btracer but its crashing.
Thank You

[image]

Comment: if you don't mind using animation nodes and installing some extra nodes it is pretty easy, just checkout this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw0hmTBGhhM

Comment: Would [motion paths](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/motion_paths.html) be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the link. I have read its possible with Animation nodes.

Comment: @MartyFouts I have to render the paths, In motion paths i am not sure if its possible to render the path.